# Building Facebook IOS friend multi-selector

Tags: ios, facebook

I want to build a friend multiselector so that my user can send a request to anyone of his friends. I know that there is the FBfriendselectorcontroller, but it does not have the option to select all friends, and I would like to have it in my app. I tried to populate a UITableview manually by getting the friend list in this way:

permissions (logged in using the log-in button):

```
NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends", nil];
self.loginView.readPermissions = permissions;
```

data:

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/friends"
                                 parameters:nil
                                 HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                          completionHandler:^(
                                              FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error
                                              ) {

                              //NSArray *data = [result objectForKey:@"data"];

                              NSLog(@"%@", result);

                              NSMutableDictionary* params =   [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", result], @"to", @"send", @"action_type", @"YOUR_OBJECT_ID", @"object_id", nil];

                              [FBWebDialogs
                               presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                               message:@"Take this bomb to blast your way to victory!"
                               title:nil
                               parameters:params
                               handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {}
                               ];

                          }];
```

the friend count returns 318, but the "data" is like this: (). I also tried the:

```
FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestForMyFriends];
    [friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                  NSDictionary* result,
                                                  NSError *error){

        NSArray* friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
```

but the data is null. What am I doing wrong??!!

Comment: what request do you want to send exactly? because you will ONLY get the friends who are using the app too, not ALL friends.

Comment: @luschn I want to send the request to all friends, with or without the app. Actually, if possible, only to people with an iOS device...

Comment: well, that is not possible. check out the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: @luschn the filtering feature is not that important, but I can't seem to get the friend list

Comment: as i said, read the changelog. you cannot get the friend list, you can only get friends who are using your app too. this has been answered several times on stackoverflow.

Comment: @luschn then how is it possible that Facebook talks in a section of his docs about the custom multi-friend picker to get friend's ID's to then pass on to the request dialogue?? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/multi-friend-selector/v2.1 : "Get a list of friends via the Graph API"

Comment: invitable_friends is what you mean. if you would have read everything in the link you posted, you would know that it can only be used for games with a canvas implementation.

Comment: @luschn does this mean that if my app is a game I cannot send a request to all the friends to use my app? Can I tell facebook that my app is a game just to use this feature? Thanks

Comment: if your game is a game, you can use invitable_friends. but ONLY if it is a game on apps.facebook.com. don´t use it if your app is not a game. facebook would not like it, i guess.